# How to put in the same element, components vertically and horizontally with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with a design. In desktop, I use Bootstrap 3 but I have also used flex. I tried both. I have 8 columns.
In desktop,

[image]

In mobile

[image]

I don’t find how to do it in one design. One design for desktop, one design for mobile, it’s not a problem. Is It possible to do it in one design?
Thank you

Comment: You mean, having the same look on both devices ?

Comment: No, the design is very different. these are the images

Comment: I meant : what do you want ? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Now I need to create two different page one to desktop and one to phone and I want to do in one page.

Comment: I'll give you a sample, but [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) is the documentation about responsive in bootstrap.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. If I read the comments, I understand your images are the result you want. It is correct ? Edit your question and add your code, the current result and what you want. It's hard to understand like it this now.
But if your images are what you want, yes bootstrap and css can do it

Answer (score 0):

For me with bootstrap it's impossible without separating the code. In desktop you can create

```
<div class="col-md-2">1801290001</div>
<div class="col-md-2">Roldán Rodriguéz, David</div>
<div class="col-md-1">-</div>
<div class="col-md-1">Absentismo</div>
<div class="col-md-1">30/05/2018</div>
<div class="col-md-1">30/05/2018</div>
<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn recruitment">PDTE. 
CONTRACIÓN</button></div>
```

and in phone you need

```
     <div class="col-1 col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" value=""></div>
     <div class="col-10 flex-column">
     <div >1801290001</div>
     <div >Roldán Rodriguéz, David</div>
     <div >-</div>
     <div >Absentismo</div>
     <div >30/05/2018</div>
     <div >30/05/2018</div>
     <div ><button type="button" class="btn recruitment">PDTE. CONTRACIÓN</button> 
         </div>
</div>
```